# Typewriter effect and links

Tags: javascript, jquery

my JS skills are really poor if not to say none.
I search for a typewriter effect withs links in the text. I have a very simple code running

the page is responsive and the nice about this code is, that it is so simple, automatically line breaks on small devices, respects my CSS ...

now I want TERM1-4 to be links which obviously doesn't work with this code.
There are tons of examples out there, but none of them seems to fit my very simple requirements and come with very heavy JS files.
anybody can help me with how to link these 4 words, please?!

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = '/ Term1 / Term2 / Term3 / Term4';
var speed = 100;    
function typeWriter() {
      if (i < txt.length) {
        document.getElementById("typeIt").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
      }
    }   
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(typeWriter, 700);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="typeIt"></div>
```

Comment: Do you want to add <a href='#'>Term1</a> all your words while your code is typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I update your texts as an array to store and process them one by one easily. Then, I didn't change your simple solution, I just update it to run on an array that I defined above.

When word1 (Term 1) end, it will jump Term2 and start it from the begining with the same flow that you made.

Last, If you end of the array you didn't call your function again to don't get any console error. To do this I check the `j` variable is suitable to increase on the `else` block.

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var txt = ['Term1','Term2','Term3','Term4'];
var seperator = ' / ';
var links = ['link1','link2','link3','link4'];
var speed = 100;    

function typeWriter() {
      if (i < txt[j].length) {
        if(! $("#c"+j).length){ //check the element is created or not
            $("#typeIt").append("<a href='"+links[j]+"' id='c"+j+"'></a>"); // if it is not create element first
        }

        $("#c"+j).append(txt[j].charAt(i++));   //and append the next char
        
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
      }
      else{
        i=0;
        if(++j < txt.length) {
            $("#typeIt").append(seperator);
            setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
        }
      }
      
    }   

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(typeWriter, 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="typeIt"></div>
```

Comment: awesome, thx a lot 
that works fine and is 99% perfect

any chance to link just the terms and not the slashes as well?

Comment: 99.9% now, the seperator is fine, but now is only BETWEEN the terms
actually the slash should be leading all the terms

Comment: starts with '/ ' slash plus space for TERM1 and then ' / ' to seperate

Comment: never mind I got it
simply placed a trailing slash and space into the #typeIt and not all is perfect

thx a lot, that workz perfect now !!! 
rgds and stay healthy, the
skyfreak

Comment: @skyfreak42 happy to hear that. Do not forget upvote true answers and verify the answer that solved the problem

Comment: thx again for your superduper help, may I ask you one more thing please. with your code every single letter of each term is wrapped in an anchor which makes loads of anchors in source code ... any way to wrap the whole term in an anchor instead of each sinlge letter?

Comment: @skyfreak42 I updated my answer as you comment and also I change your javascript selectors and functions with JQuery selectors and functions

Comment: oh my god it doesn't seem to end :-( I will make a new answer as I cannot post code in the comment

Answer (score 1):

```js
var i = 0;
var linkIndex = 0;
var texts = ['/ Term1 ','/ Term2 ','/ Term3 ','/ Term4']
links = ['htt://ww.example1.de','htt://www.example2.de','htt://www.example3.de','htt://www.example4.de']
var speed = 100;    
function typeWriter() {
    if(i==0) {
       document.getElementById("typeIt").innerHTML += `<a href="${links[linkIndex]}" id="link${linkIndex}"></a>`
    }
    if (i < links[linkIndex].length) {
        document.getElementById(`link${linkIndex}`).innerHTML += texts[linkIndex].charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }else if(linkIndex < links.length-1){
        linkIndex += 1;
        i = 0;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(typeWriter, 700);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="typeIt"></div>
```

Comment: thx, the code from @oguzhancerit is somehow nice, as it does not pause after each term

Answer (score 0):

the code of @oguzhancerit works perfect ... for normal links in the href
but I want to use these links as page anchors so I changed the code slightly like this

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var txt = ['term1','term2','term4','term4'];
var seperator = ' / ';
var dataSrcollTo = ['#el-term1','#el-term2','#el-term3','#el-term4'];
var speed = 100;    

function typeWriter() {
      if (i < txt[j].length) {
        if(! $("#typeIT-c"+j).length){ //check the element is created or not
            $("#typeIt").append("<a href='#' data-scrollto=\""+dataSrcollTo[j]+"\" data-easing=\"easeInOutExpo\" data-speed=\"1250\" data-offset=\"0\" id='typeIT-c"+j+"'></a>"); // if it is not create element first
        }

        $("#typeIT-c"+j).append(txt[j].charAt(i++));   //and append the next char
        
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
      }
      else{
        i=0;
        if(++j < txt.length) {
            $("#typeIt").append(seperator);
            setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
        }
      }
      
    }   

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(typeWriter, 300);
});
```

console doesn't throw errors and the code in inspector looks proper for each of the 4 links.

the problem now, is that it does not scroll when clicking the links
and a guess is, that the id typeIt is empty and filled with the content after the JS that handles the scrolling is loaded.

is there a way to fill the code in the id typeIt instead of having an empty element, and make it than typeing?

because when I fill the paragraph id typeIt like so without using the typewriting effect

```
<p id="typeIt">
    / <a href="#" data-scrollto="#el-term1" data-easing="easeInOutExpo" data-speed="1250" data-offset="0">Term1</a> 
    / <a href="#" data-scrollto="#el-term2" data-easing="easeInOutExpo" data-speed="1250" data-offset="0">Term2</a>
    / <a href="#" data-scrollto="#el-term3" data-easing="easeInOutExpo" data-speed="1250" data-offset="0">Term3</a>
    / <a href="#" data-scrollto="#el-term4" data-easing="easeInOutExpo" data-speed="1250" data-offset="0">Term4</a>
</p>
```

the scrolling workz. hope I explained well where the problem is now.

Comment: SOLVED - the main JS of the template uses a scrollto function. this function needed to be included into the if statement of the typewriter function and now the typewriter effect workz like a wanted it to. thx to all for helping and especially of cause to @oguzhancerit. may all of you and your beloved ones stay healthy and a happier 2021 for all of us.